# Static Method -- Is it usual behavior?

Tags: c#-2.0, static-methods

Have a small doubt with static method.

Documentation says that "Static method can't access instance member variable OR static methods and properties can only access static fields and static events since it's gets executed much before an instance is created". So, the below code fails to compile

```
class staticclass
{
    int a = 20; //Private member

    public static void staticmethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value Of Instance member variable is: {0}",a);  // Error
    }

}
```

But we also know that, inside a static method we can create an instance of the same class.

So, changing the above code a bit I can access the instance variable in static method

```
class staticclass
{
    int a = 20; //PRivate Memeber

    public static void staticmethod()
    {
        staticclass sc = new staticclass(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Value Of Instance member variable is: {0}",sc.a);  
    }

}
```

This Compiles fine and displays the result `Value Of Instance member variable is: 20`.

Is this a normal behavior? OR I am not able to understand it correctly?

I mean, if this the case then How the statements holds true `static methods can only access static fields`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what static means – it means that you only have access to static members of `this`. It doesn't restrict you accessing another object's non-static members.

The fact that the "other" object you're accessing in your static method happens to be an instance of the same class does not matter.